# use Intent in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When we want to move to another `Activity` using `Intent` in `Kotlin`, it gives this error.

In `Intent`, it doesn't recognize `.java` after `::class`

**look:**

[image]

And when I delete `.java`, `Intent` gives an error

[image]

***Note*: My problem was not solved with `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` option in `File`**

*I don't know where the problem is. please help me.*

Comment: Hi. Please add code as text, not images. Why? Because then we'll have to spend time on typing in every code line from your question into our tests. BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

**In `build.gradle (:app)` file, in `dependencies`, you should change `appcompat` version to `1.4.2`.**

befor error:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    ...
}
```

And when I changed the version to `1.4.2`, the problem was solved

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    ...
}
```

**And make sure the `kotlin` version is `1.5.0`**

Answer (score 0):

Kinda strange because it seems good to me. Try this.

Remove the lateinit and declare it directly when you need it, maybe it will solve the problem.

```
val intent = Intent(this, LauncherActivity::class.java)
```

I don't think the `this@KotlinActivity` is needed in this case. 
Let me know if this fix it

UPDATE

Are you sure the `findViewById<TextView>...` is correct ? Shouldn't it has a declaration before ? Like

```
val view = findViewById<>...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the solution